# Unable to launch the application

Tags: java, javafx, launch

I'm making a simple game in JavaFX and I have a problem with running the application. I use NetBeans 6.9.1. The application type is "JavaFX Script Application".

When I build project, it creates four files in the folder `dist`. These are:

- `BcJavaFX.html` file
- `BcJavaFX.jar` file
- `BcJavaFX.jnlp` file
- `BcJavaFX_browser.jnlp` file

On the computer where I'm developing this game, the game runs after opening `BcJavaFX.jnlp` or `BcJavaFX_browser.jnlp`. With `BcJavaFX_browser.jnlp` the game runs in a browser. With `BcJavaFX.jnlp` the game run in classic window. Next to the top right corner by window is a small exclamation mark. When I hover over the exclamation mark with the mouse, the text *"Java Application Window"* is diplayed. But the application runs correctly.

The problem is that the application does not run on other computerss. When I open the files `BcJavaFX.jnlp` or `BcJavaFX_browser.jnlp` on other computers, a window is shown with the message *"Unable to launch the application"*. The exception details are:

```
Exception    
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: http://localhost:8082/servlet/org.netbeans.modules.javafx.project.JnlpDownloadServlet/C%3A/Dulezite-SKOLA/BcPrace/opengl/JavaFXApplication4/dist/JavaFXApplication4.jnlp
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.updateFinalLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Wrapped Exception

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.updateFinalLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

But when I start a foreign downloaded game (e.g. http://www.remwebdevelopment.com/javaFX-game-tutorial/Blasteroids.zip ), the game runs correctly on all computers. Where is problem please?

Comment: For one, the URL `htp://localhost:8082/…` looks wrong, that should probably be `http://`. Is this a typo in the question or an error in your code?

Comment: I rewrite http on htp because when I wanted add this question, display some error related with hyperlink http://localhost:8082/....

Comment: Hm, might be a new user restriction. Anyway, I'm not really sure how JNLP and Netbeans works, but is the server that the JNLP points to running on others' computers? Since it's trying to download something from `localhost:8082`, there should be something running on that port on the others' computers. Alternately, you might have to host the JNLP and the stuff it needs somewhere else. (Like a Dropbox folder.)

Comment: ok thank for tip, I try solve this problem.